# Python mysql insert when record does not exist

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table with articles like this:

Table: artPerBrand

Colums: ID (auto increment), BrandID, ArtCat, ArtNrShort, ArtNrLong, Active

I want to insert new articles (using a python script) but only if the same ArtNrLong does not already exist.

I cannot do this by making the ArtNrLong unique beacause I have multiple scenarios where, sometimes, I can be possible to have the same ArtNrLong in the table.

So I created this sql statement based on this input (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table/).

```
  cur.execute ("INSERT INTO artPerBrand (BrandID, ArtCat, ArtNrShort, ArtNrLong, Active)\
select * from (Select" + varBrandID, varArtCat, varArtNrShort, varArtNrLong,1 +") as temp \
where not exists (Select ArtNrLong from artPerBrand where ArtNrLong="+varArtNrLong+") LIMIT 1")
```

I also tried this option:

```
  sql = "INSERT INTO artPerBrand(BrandID, ArtCat, ArtNrShort, ArtNrLong, Active) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM artPerBrand WHERE ArtNrLong = %s)" 
val = (varBrandID, varArtCat, varArtNrShort, varArtNrLong 1, varArtNrLong)
cur.execute(sql, val)
```

I get a general error, telling me the query is wrong.
Am I mistaking some quotes here, or something?

Combining the help in the comments brought me the solution:

```
      sql = "INSERT INTO artPerBrand(BrandID, ArtCat, ArtNrShort, ArtNrLong, Active) SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, %s FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM artPerBrand WHERE ArtNrLong = %s)" 
val = (varBrandID, varArtCat, varArtNrShort, varArtNrLong 1, varArtNrLong)
cur.execute(sql, val)
```

Comment: 1. You should use a unique index for preventing duplicate values from being insert, not this overcomplicated query. 2) If you insist on using the query in question, then put the sql query first into a string variable and print out the sql statement and I'm pretty sure you will see where the syntax goes wrong. Hint: you need spaces and list of variables is also wrong. 3) Use parameters, not string concatenation.

Comment: I get articles from different sources. From one source the ArtNrLong is unique from another source the ArtNrShort is unique. This is why I, think, need this more complicated solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      sql = "INSERT INTO artPerBrand(BrandID, ArtCat, ArtNrShort, ArtNrLong, Active) SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, %s FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM artPerBrand WHERE ArtNrLong = %s)" 
val = (varBrandID, varArtCat, varArtNrShort, varArtNrLong 1, varArtNrLong)
cur.execute(sql, val)
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Yes the query is incorrect.

```
Select" + varBrandID, varArtCat, varArtNrShort, varArtNrLong,1 +
```

What it should be

```
Select" + varBrandID+", "+ varArtCat", "+ varArtNrShort", "+ varArtNrLong", "+ 1 +
```

Secondly, if they are integer values you can't add them, you have to use

```
str(varBrandID)
```

If you want to use them as integers, Don't concatenate them, assign them

```
"select %d,%d,%d,%d from x"%(val1,val2,val3,val4)
```

Comment: I combined this wit the "FROM Dual". That works for me.